# How to handle new line in handlebar.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile, handlebars.js

I am using HandleBar.js in my rails jquery mobile application.

I have a json returned value `data= "hi\n\n\n\n\nb\n\n\n\nhow r u"`

which when used in .hbs file as `{{data}}` showing me as `hi how r u` and not as with the actual new line inserted

Please suggest me.

**Pre tag helps me**

Comment: Maybe this can help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331077/does-handlebars-js-replace-newline-characters-with-br

Answer (score 4):

Handlebars doesn't mess with newlines in your data unless you have registered a helper which is doing something with them. A good way of dealing with newlines in HTML without converting them to `br` tags would be to use the CSS property `white-space` while rendering the handlebars template in HTML. You can set its value to `pre-line`.

[Read the related documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source of the generated file - your newline characters are probably there, HTML simply does not render newline characters as new lines.

You can insert a linebreak with `<br />`

However, it looks like you're trying to format the position of your lines using newline characters, which technically should be done by wrapping your lines in `<p>` or `<div>` tags and styling with CSS.

Comment: No in the source also it doesnt have any new lines. But its saved with \n in table..

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the CSS property *white-space* and set the value as *pre-line*

For a example:

```html
<p style="white-space: pre-line">
  {{text}}
</p>
```

Comment: This was already suggested by [the accepted answer from seven years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27773380/3025856). Please don't repeat answers.