# How to pass a line break in Marionette templateHelper / templateContext?

Tags: javascript, html, marionette

For the given view, in Marionette 2.4.4:

```
var view = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  template: Handlebars.compile('{{body}}'),
  templateHelpers: function(){
    return {
      body: "Line one. Line Two.",
    };
  }
});

view = new view();
MasterView.showChildView('master_content', view);
```

What do I need to add to the "body" property to make "Line one." appear on a line above "Line Two." once rendered?

Note: templateHelpers became templateContext in newer versions of Marionette.

Experiments: `<br>` does not work. It is simply shown as plaintext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `<br>` didn't work is due to Handlebars, not Marionette. As per [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331077/does-handlebars-js-replace-newline-characters-with-br), to make Handlebars not escape html expressions, use `{{{}}}` triple braces, instead of `{{}}`. Thus, the following code works:

```
var view = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  template: Handlebars.compile('{{body}}'),
  templateHelpers: function(){
    return {
      body: "Line one. {{{<br>}}} Line Two.",
    };
  }
});

view = new view();
MasterView.showChildView('master_content', view);
```

Comment: This is close.  The {{{ is not needed in the body string it is need in the template string around `{{{ body }}}` in the `compile` function.  The string itself can just be "Line one.<br>Line Two."